# How to refresh the datatable after updated value with SqlCommand statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, datatable

I have `DataTable` that was loaded with a `SqlDataReader` query. After my `DataTable` is loaded, I do looping that I was insert data with a `SqlCommand` every index. But the `DataTable` is not refreshed. How to refresh the `DataTable` while data is updated in the database?

```
    connectionx()
        Dim dtreader As SqlDataReader
        Dim cmddt As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from sometable", con)

        dtreader = cmddt.ExecuteReader()

        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
        dt.Load(dtreader) 'Here from datareader


        For index As Integer = currentRow To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim drR As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
            Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader

            Dim EP As DateTime
            Dim EndW As String = dtnow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
            Dim setEndWaiting As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(adapterSch.SetEndWTime(EndW, Convert.ToInt32(Session("ShipLoadingOrderFK"))))


                Dim startPre As DateTime = EndW
                Dim endPre As DateTime = startPre + TimeSpan.Parse(defPre)
                Dim setPreDocumentTime As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(adapterSch.SetPreDocumentTime(startPre, endPre, Convert.ToInt32(Session("ShipLoadingOrderFK"))))

                Dim startPump As DateTime = endPre
                Dim endPump As DateTime
                Dim shipKey As String = Shipid.SelectedValue
                pumpigResult(MinutePumpResult, HoursPumpResult, FlowrateValue, Shipid.SelectedValue, Loading_No.Value, typeLoading.SelectedValue)
                If FlowrateValue = 0 Or FlowrateValue = "" Then
                    endPump = endPre + TimeSpan.Parse(defPumping)
                Else
                    endPump = endPre + New TimeSpan(HoursPumpResult, MinutePumpResult, 0)
                End If
                Dim setPumpTime As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(adapterSch.SetPumpingTime(startPump, endPump, Convert.ToInt32(Session("ShipLoadingOrderFK"))))

                Dim startPost As DateTime = endPump
                Dim endPost As DateTime = endPump + TimeSpan.Parse(defPost)
                Dim setPostTime As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(adapterSch.SetPostTime(startPost, endPost, Convert.ToInt32(Session("ShipLoadingOrderFK"))))
```

After insert data while every index with code above. I have get the value on previous row (index-1), but I get the **OLD Data before updated**.

```
Dim EP as datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows(index - 1)("PostDocEnd").ToString())
```

How to refresh the `DataTable` so that I can get the previous data that has been updated? I have try to re-load `DataTable` again, but is nothing.

Thank you

Comment: Event though there is a lot of code there, you dont actually shjow anything related to the problem described.  There is no insert, no "refresh".  I dont see the point of that loop or the new row created

Comment: Why you start loop with currentRow and where you set the initial value. I don't see Next for For statement. It seems that code is not complete. You create new row drR  and not initialized within loop. Review your code and complete it so we can help discovering the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
I just line code for reload datareader at starting index looping and refresh the datatable.

```
    dt.reset()
    dtreader = cmddt.ExecuteReader()
    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
    dt.Load(dtreader)
```

It will be reload the datatable while database is changed.